# How to debug a DebuggerTypeProxy proxy?

Tags: c#, .net, debugging

I've developed several proxies that I specify on their nesting types using the `DebuggerTypeProxyAttribute` on the type declaration. But when these proxies have bugs in them, it's difficult to debug. I haven't found a way to step through the proxy using the debugger (a nested debugging session).

Any pointers on how to do this?

Comment: BTW, sometime in the past I'm pretty sure I was able to attach a debugger to devenv.exe (yes, two IDEs open at once) while the devenv.exe debuggee was debugging my app, and thus set breakpoints on the type proxy to see what's going on. But lately that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: I did that all the time with debugging t4 templates. I am surprised it did not work for debugger type proxies.

Answer (score 2):

Try manually creating instances of the type proxy and evaluating its properties. If you do so in the Immediate Window while debugging in Visual Studio, breakpoints in the type proxy will be working. Just make sure to remove the `[DebuggerTypeProxy]` attribute from your types during this process so you have complete control over when these instances are created.

Comment: Good tip, although in my case the failure seems to only occur when the debugger view is the one instantiating the proxy. It's very particular, for example, about requiring any thread switches or lock acquisitions. In the case I'm facing right now, the debugger seems to ignore the proxy altogether. So while it works perfectly if I execute it myself, I need to know why the debugger is ignoring it.

Answer (score 2):

Inspired by Sam's response, I've been able to do this with only one debugger in VS2013:

1) Attach a debugger to a process that has a type that you wish to inspect via a debugger type proxy, and

2) Instantiate the debugger type proxy in the immediate window:

`new YourDebuggerTypeProxy(thingBeingDebugged)`

Your debugger should break within the debugger type proxy. This seems to be because VS injects code generated through the immediate window directly into the attached process.